# codeigniter gives a forbidden response on a simple ajax load function

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to use ajax inside my codeigniter application and getting a forbidden response
Is it a way to deal with that without using codeigniter load method.

Comment: Do you have more info to provide ?
Did you looked for .htaccess solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help, but CI usually comes with a .htaccess file in the application directory and I think it's set to deny all.  Check if that is there first, it might be messing things up for you.